# How to take user input and insert it into an array?

Tags: julia

New to Julia, trying to simply ask the user to choose 5 numbers and put it into an array and print the array. My output only says pick 5 numbers with "nothing" followed underneath.  I cant seem to figure out why it wont read my inputs.

```
function ask()
   lst = []
   i = 0
   println("pick 5 numbers to add to a list")
   while i < 5
     choice = readline
     choice = push!(lst, choice);
     i += 1
    end 
end
 
println(ask())
```

Answer (score 3):

You were assigning function reference to list elements rather than calling the function.

This should be:

```
function ask()
   lst = String[]
   i = 0
   println("pick 5 numbers to add to a list")
   while i < 5
     choice = readline()
     choice = push!(lst, choice);
     i += 1
   end 
   lst
end
```

If you want numbers rather than `String`s the last line could be `parse.(Int, lst)` or you could add this conversion near `readline`

Note that if you do not plan to introduce some error checking etc. this all code could be simply written as:

```
println("pick 5 numbers to add to a list")
lst = [parse(Int, readline()) for _ in 1:5]
```